# Make a auto adjust multiple image in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in html programming. I want to give margin from top with span class, Give me some idea about this problem.

Comment: Post some code here, what you did so far? Post your problem demo to get solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Varun. When asking questions related to debugging, please post minimal relevant code snippets along with a description of your problem on your question. Check out this link for tips on how to ask qeustions in SO: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Varun. When asking questions related to debugging, please post minimal relevant code snippets along with a description of your problem on your question. Check out this link for tips on how to ask qeustions in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Span is an in-line element so you can not add a margin to it.

You can use padding or make the span display:inline-block; and then use margins.

example

```
<span>hello</span>

span{
     display:inline-block;
     margin-top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### [8.3 Margin properties:](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'
>
> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements.**

`<span>` is an inline element. So either use a block (or inline-block) element or apply `display: block` or `display: inline-block` CSS styling to the element.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using div tags instead.

For example;

```
<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>


#myDiv {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000; margin: 10px; }
```